# Export a ruby array into a column in a csv file

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I have an array and I'd like to export it into a csv file. However, I want each value of the array to be on a new row, so that the final csv file is one column containing all the array values.  What's the most elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this, but here's one:

```
require 'csv'
myarray = ["something", "something, also", "\"something\""]
CSV.open("my file.csv", "w") do |f|
  myarray.each do |x|
    f << [x]
  end
end
```

- require the CSV module
- use it to open a file
- use `<<` to write each row, where here a row is just a one-element array with one item from your original array

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["baz", "woo"],
]
.flatten.map{|e| [e]}
# =>
# [
#   ["foo"],
#   ["bar"],
#   ["baz"],
#   ["woo"],
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write elements of array in each line:

```
ary = ["goat", "cat", ["alien", "planet"]].flatten

File.open("a.csv", "w") do |f|
  f.write(ary.join("\n"))
end
```